# RPI Zero W gadget after plugging in turns my PC off

Tags: usb, pi-zero, usb-power, pi-zero-w, gadget

Hello I am making a rpi zero USB gadget but something is wrong with it I am sure that pads don't connect to each other [image: my setup]

Comment: This is almost certainly caused by a wiring or power issue. You are "sure your wiring does not touch", have you tested that assertion with a multimeter? You also assume that the connection problem is not at the other end of the wires shown. I would suggest removing the wires you have added and testing with a standard USB cable (before you damage your Pi or computer).

Comment: Are you supplying the Raspberry Pi Zero from a USB port on the PC?

Comment: @MatsK Yes i am